# How to configure Node-RED Docker to write output files into the "data" directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-red, docker-volume

I use node-red with docker with a docker-compose file (https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker)

When I write a file from a flow (with node-red:file) the file is written **into the container** in this directory :

```
/usr/src/node-red
```

In my docker-compose file I use a volume to make data persistent

```
    volumes:
      - /local/path/to/node-red/data:/data
```

So when I write a file from a flow I would like to write the file **outside the container** in the **same directory** where all other users data are stored :

```
/local/path/to/node-red/data
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure the file node, use the full path name of the file you want it to write - start it with `/data` . Otherwise it defaults to the working directory of the Node-RED process.